# python how to make list and print it

Tags: python

hi I am very very new in python and write a function

```
def makeList(x,c):

  if(isinstance( x, int )) and (isinstance(x,chr)):
    mylist = []
    for i in range(c):
    mylist.append(x)
    print mylist
  else:
      print ' Sorry, but 'Hello' is not a valid length.'
      return
```

it simply define a function and print the list. 
I just can not run it and out put like this

```
>>> myList = makeList('a',5)
>>> myList
  ['a','a','a','a','a']

>>> makeList(3,12)
  [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]

>>> myList = makeList(7,"Hello")
  Sorry, but 'Hello' is not a valid length.
>>> myList 
  None
```

I have a error when I run it can somebody tell me why? 
thank u veryvery much

Comment: Just so you know, you dont need to append like you have done. you can use the `*` operator. For example, `[3]*5` = `[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]`. `['a']*5` = `['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `chr` type in Python, use `str` instead. From [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html):

> The items of a string are characters. There is no separate character type; a character is represented by a string of one item.

Also I think you want to check if `c` is an integer and `x` is a `str`:

```
if(isinstance(c, int)) and (isinstance(x, str)):
```

Also, you have to indent the line

```
mylist.append(x)
```

so it is in the body of the `for` loop. And in order to make your function `makeList` return a list, you have to add a `return` statement:

```
return mylist
```

Your code will look like:

```
def makeList(x, c):
    if(isinstance(c, int)) and (isinstance(x, str)):
        mylist = []
        for i in range(c):
            mylist.append(x)
        return mylist
    else:
        print " Sorry, but 'Hello' is not a valid length."
        return
```

Answer (score 1):

adding to @Christian answer, in python you'd use duck typing instead of checking the instance type, one version of makeList can be:

```
 >>> def makeList(x,c):
 ...     try:
 ...         return [x]*c
 ...     except TypeError:
 ...         print " Sorry, but 'Hello' is not a valid length."
 ... 
 >>> 
 >>> makeList(7,"Hello")
  Sorry, but 'Hello' is not a valid length.
 >>> makeList(3,12)
 [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
 >>> makeList('a',5)
 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

also see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175655/python-forgiveness-vs-permission-and-duck-typing

Answer (score 0):

Did you realised that your parameters are the other way around in the last call?

```
>>> makeList(3,12)
  [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
>>> myList = makeList(7,"Hello")
```

That may be why doesn't work that time.

Also have in mind the suggestion done of change from chr to str